# using the xmldiffpatch class of microsoft with an attribute as ID

Tags: c#, xml, diff

I want to use the xmldiffpatch class of microsoft
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa302294.aspx

now is the question how I can say that I want to use the attribute **model** as my ID?

```
<PartPriceInfo xmlns:ns1="http://www.Subaru.com">
   <ns1:Subaru model="Legacy">
      <ns1:Muffler> 400 </ns1:Muffler>
      <ns1:Bumper> 100 </ns1:Bumper>
      <ns1:Floormat> 50 </ns1:Floormat>
      <ns1:WindShieldWipers> 20 </ns1:WindShieldWipers>
   </ns1:Subaru>
   <ns1:Subaru model="Outback">
      <ns1:Muffler> 500 </ns1:Muffler>
      <ns1:Bumper> 150 </ns1:Bumper>
      <ns1:Floormat> 75 </ns1:Floormat>
      <ns1:WindShieldWipers> 20 </ns1:WindShieldWipers>
   </ns1:Subaru>
</PartPriceInfo>
```

regards Chris

Comment: Could you provide some clarification to your question? I'm not sure how what you are asking is related to XMLDiffPatch.